# Integration using substitution: $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1 - x^2)}\arcsin^3x} dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

I am trying to solve this integration:

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1 - x^2)}\arcsin^3x} dx $$

using **substitution**.
My problem is that I can not find the right way to use substitution in this case.

The result should be:

$$ C- \frac{1}{2(\arcsin^2x)}$$

note: I guess that I should use this formula:

$$ \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx = \arcsin x + C $$

Thank you.

Comment: Your formula for the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$ is not correct. If you fix that (double check the derivative of arcsin x), you should see easily how to do the problem.

Comment: Ohh, I know... I have just wrote it wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that the derivative of $\arcsin(x)$ appears in this integrand.  In general, this tells us that $u$-substitution would be a good thing to try; in our case, if we let $u = \arcsin(x)$, we get $\displaystyle du = \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}$.  Thus our integral becomes:

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x^2} \ \arcsin^3(x)} \ dx \ =\  \int \frac{1}{u^3} \ du$$

Comment: So easy... :) Thanks.

Comment: Yep!  Just takes practice doing a ton of these sorts of problems

Comment: I know! Sometimes I just do not see it (need more practice). :)